# How to connect between MySQL and Eclipse Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database

How do I establish database connectivity between MySQL and Eclipse Java?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways:

- [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/)
- [EJB](http://java.sun.com/products/ejb/) (make sure you go with version 3!)
- Roll your own solution with [JDO/JDBC](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/database/)

And I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need a JDBC driver for MySQL in your application classpath which then registers automatically with DriverManager.

You can then use the techniques described in http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html except you need to have the connection string (starting with jdbc:...) adapted to your precise scenario.  That is described in the documentation for the JDBC driver you choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of jdbc tutorials if you want to build your own solution.  MYsql has a [Using MySQL With Java](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/) page that has links to tutorials, presentations, blogs etc.  The first tutorial looks like it covers everything from installing the database to accessing it from the java program.